# Can I stop certain sections of code excution after it's intetend function or work is done?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Sorry for not posting any code as I have no idea about this logic.

I have a while loop where it runs as soon as the user presses the button and stops after he presses again. But I have a condition that needed to be checked for small period of time until it's condition gets satisfied(Timer will not satisfy my need). So I want to execute that part of code until it satisfies that condition and after that I do not need that part of the code to check that condition or in other words I want the program to stop executing that part of code so that I can save my execution time wasted for that part of code.

So is this possible? Or it's something that we can not achieve in programming?

Please note, I don't want to implement a timer to get this done!

Edited(Work i need to established)

It's accelerometer updates that i m checking...Updates start as the user presses the button. I have set a condition to check whether it exceeds a certain value, If exceeded i wanted to store a count to a global variable. Then after as i said, I dnt need it to repeat checking for that condition.As i m not going to stop accel data once started unless stop by the user by pressing the button?

Comment: Are you worrying about the extra processing of an `if` statement? There's no harm in checking a state variable each time round your loop to see which bit of code to run.

Comment: I think you need to give us a bit more context and explain the practical application of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Kev It's accelerometer updates that i m checking...Updates get On by a button. I have a set a condition to check whether it exceeds a certain value, If exceeded i wanted to store a count to a global variable. Then after as i said, I dnt need it to repeat checking for that condition.As i m not going to stop accel data once started unless stop by the user by pressing the button?

Comment: Can you edit this information into the question? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what your code *will* look like... but yes, this is something you can easily accomplish [via Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) (i.e. register for "`NSNotifications`" and when some condition is satisfied, it posts a notification and then any other objects listening will run a selector to "stop").  Or you can have your other threads monitoring some condition [via Key-Value-Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html), so when some BOOL condition (that each of your sections of code are observing) changes, they can finish up whatever they're doing.

Hopefully this makes sense so far, but the overall idea is "yes, what you're asking for shouldn't be too hard to do".

Comment: +1 for the answer, But if i explain more about the code, It's accelerometer updates that i m checking... I have a set a condition to check whether it exceeds a certain value, If exceeded i wanted to store a count to a global variable. Then after as i said, I dnt need it to repeat checking for that condition. I have a bit knowledge about Notifications, But is this possible. As i m not going to stop accel data once started unless stop by the user by pressing the button?

Comment: you still can use Notifications or KVO to do what you're trying to do.  if some condition passes, you can update a global variable or stop the accelerometer updates from happening or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(mainCondition)
{
    if(!extraCondidion)
    {
        // Do extra bit of code only until extra condition is met
    }

    // Do normal code that runs before and after extra condition is met
}
```